# Object.assign({}, item) to merge objects into one doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, object, async-await

In first API call I'm getting an array of IDs to be able to make another API call to grab revenue key/value pairs, then push it back to the main object(as it doesn't have it by default).

```
const mainURL =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=2339027b84839948cd9be5de8b2b36da&language=en-US&sort_by=revenue.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=";
const movieBaseURL =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/335?api_key=2339027b84839948cd9be5de8b2b36da&language=en-US";
const apiKey = "2339027b84839948cd9be5de8b2b36da";
let getRevenueByID,revenue, data, response, obj;
let Each_ID_Array = [],
  All_ID_Array = [],
  All_ID_Array_merged = [],
  pages_Array = [1, 2],
  keyValueArr = [],
  allKeyValueArr = [],
  objectArr = [];
  responses = [];
  newData = [];
let text = "";

//fetch function 
let getSearchResultsForOnePage = url => {
  //fetch
  return fetch(url);
};

//Function to cool down requests
let pause = time => {
  // handy pause function to await
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
};

//Get main object for d3 visualisation
getAllSearchResultProfiles = async searchURL => {
  let URLs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < pages_Array.length; i++) {
    URLs.push(searchURL + pages_Array[i]);
  }
  console.log(URLs);
  for (let url of URLs) {
    console.log("sending request");
    response = await getSearchResultsForOnePage(url);
    console.log("received", response);
    responses.push(await response.json());
    await pause(500);
  }

  console.log('responses', responses);

  return responses;
};

//Function to get revenue by ID
getRevenueByID = async (arr) => {
    let resObj = {}; // Is an complete result
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      console.log("ID is: ", arr[i]);

      getRevenueURL = await fetch(
        "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" +
          arr[i] +
          "?api_key=" +
          apiKey +
          "&language=en-US"
      );
      let data = await getRevenueURL.json();
      console.log("data received: ", data);
      await pause(200);

      //return key/value array
      keyValueArr = Object.entries(data)[16];
      console.table(keyValueArr);

      allKeyValueArr.push(keyValueArr);

      //convert key/value array to object
      obj = Object.assign(
        ...allKeyValueArr.map(d => ({
          [d[0]]: d[1]
        }))
      );

      console.log("object is: ", obj);
      resObj[arr[i]] = obj;
      console.log("resObj: ", resObj[arr[i]]);
    }
    console.log("OUTPUT - getRevenueByID: ", resObj);
    return resObj;
  };

(getFinalObject = async () => {
  getAllSearchResultProfiles(mainURL).then(async (data) => {
      //get movie ID's
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        Each_ID_Array = data[i].results.map(d => d.id);
        All_ID_Array.push(Each_ID_Array);
        console.table('All ID Array', All_ID_Array);
        All_ID_Array_merged = [].concat.apply([], All_ID_Array);
        console.table('All ID Array merged',All_ID_Array_merged);    

        console.log('data[i].results: ',data[i].results);

        obj = await getRevenueByID(All_ID_Array_merged);
        console.log('obj is', obj);

         //inject revenue key/value
         Object.keys(data[i].results).forEach(key => {
          console.log("The name of the current key: ", key);
          console.log("The value of the current key: ", data[i].results[key]);
          data[i].results[key]["revenue"] = obj[data[i].results[key].id]["revenue"];
          console.log('data[i].results[key]["revenue"]: ',  data[i].results[key]["revenue"]);

        });


      }

      console.log('data', data);
```

Data I'm getting is in the following format [{…}, {…}]. So instead of an array of **objects** I'm trying to get an array of **one object** [{...}] inside

```
      newData = data.map(item => 
        Object.assign({}, item)
        );

      console.log('data for visualisation is:',newData);
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));


})();
```

Comment: use reduce to get one object and then push it in array.
also Object.assign does shallow copy

Comment: That 's a lot of code. Please create a [mcve] with only variables which are relevant to the question. Also, please post a sample of `allKeyValueArr` and the expected output

Comment: Extract just problematic part and include it as code snippet.

Comment: Using `Object.entries(data)[16]` doesn't make much sense. Objects aren't ordered, so getting "the sixteenth entry" is pretty meaningless. Better specify explicitly the property that you are interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to reduce the array:

```js
 const data = [{a:1}, {b:2}];
 
 const newData = data.reduce((acc,curr) => ({...acc, ...curr}), {});
  
 console.log(newData); // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. For some reason it returns second object itself. `{page: 2, total_results: 406037, total_pages: 20302, results: Array(20)}`

Comment: @EdgarKiljak How is your data different from mine, when you put them into my snippet? `const data = ???`

Comment: this is what I have `data (2) [{…}, {…}]`  and then `{page: 2, total_results: 406039, total_pages: 20302, results: Array(20)}` first object is missing and its not merged

Comment: @EdgarKiljak And what is the result you want?

Comment: `{page: 1, total_results: 406039, total_pages: 20302, results: Array(20)}`, 
`{page: 2, total_results: 406039, total_pages: 20302, results: Array(20)}` to become one object, with the above approach  is throwing first object out and keeps the second one only.

Comment: @EdgarKiljak *to become one object* - how should the object look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190095/discussion-between-edgar-kiljak-and-ttulka).